# How to store outputs from a function to a matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab

so far I have this:

```
time=(0:15:16*1440);

data=zeros(3,length(time));
for i=1:length(time)
(not sure what goes here)=ValidateTime(0,0,time(i));
end
```

validateTime is my function that returns 3 values. 
How would I store the output from the function into the data matrix I created before?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ValidateTime(..) returns a row vector of length 3, you can transpose it to a column vector and assign in it to the i'th column in your data matrix.

```
time=(0:15:16*1440);

data=zeros(3,length(time));
for i=1:length(time)
    data(:,i)=ValidateTime(0,0,time(i))';  % Note the single quote!
end
```